# Вечная загрузка программы

Tags: python, python-3.x, графика, pygame

При попытке запустить программу она уходит в вечную загрузку, зависает и более не реагирует ни на что. В чём может быть проблема? Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
#import tkinter as tk
import pygame
import random

RUNNING = True
#root = tk.Tk()
WIDTH = 960 #root.winfo_screenwidth()
HEIGHT = 960 #root.winfo_screenheight()
FPS = 30

#BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
#WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
#RED = (255, 0, 0)
#GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
#BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
TEST_COLOR = (232, 232, 232)

#i = 0

#SIZE_CIRCLE = random.randint(32,64)
Count_Circle = 30

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Test Untitled Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def Drawning_Circle(Count_Circle, WIDTH, HEIGHT):
    Now_Count_Circle = 0
    while Now_Count_Circle != Count_Circle:
        FIRST_RANDOM_COORDINATE = random.randint(0, (WIDTH + HEIGHT) / 2)
        SECOND_RANDOM_COORDINATE = random.randint(0, (WIDTH + HEIGHT) / 2)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (32, 32, 32), 
            (FIRST_RANDOM_COORDINATE, SECOND_RANDOM_COORDINATE), 32)
        
try:
    while RUNNING:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                RUNNING = False
                pygame.quit()

        screen.fill(TEST_COLOR)
        Drawning_Circle(Count_Circle, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
        pygame.display.flip()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема возникает из-за использования цикла while. В вашем случае лучше использовать цикл for, если заранее известно количество итераций.
Вместо:

```
while Now_Count_Circle != Count_Circle:
```

Используйте:

```
for i in range(Count_Circle):
```